# Azure Devops : Set a variable for future stages and Job not working

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I am trying to generate a random string of length 32 characters in Build Stage, then I want to pass the same to the next job/deployment And Also to the next Stage.

I referred to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell to pass a variable from one job to another job and stage. But it is not working, Here is my pipeline code YAML file.

```
    trigger: none

pool:
  name: agentpool-myproj

stages:
  - stage: 'BuildStage'
    variables:
    - group: myproj-vargrp-common-dp-poc
    displayName: 'BuildStage'
    
    jobs: 
      - deployment: BuildStageSecretProducerjobs      # deployment is equal to job
        environment: dev
        displayName: 'BuildStageSecretProducerjobs'
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
              - checkout: none
              - download: none
              - task: AzurePowerShell@5
                name: mastertask
                inputs:
                  azureSubscription: 'con-myproj-dev'
                  ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
                  Inline: | 
                    $Random32Key = -join (((48..57)+(65..90)+(97..122)) |Get-Random -Count 32 |%{[char]$_}) 
                    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=supersecret;isoutput=true;issecret=false]$Random32Key"
                  FailOnStandardError: true
                  azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion

      - deployment: BuildStageSecretConsumerjobs
        dependsOn: BuildStageSecretProducerjobs
        variables:
          thissupersecret: $[ dependencies.BuildStageSecretProducerjobs.outputs['masterjob.supersecret'] ]
        environment: dev
        displayName: 'BuildStageSecretConsumer'
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
              - checkout: none
              - download: none
              - task: PowerShell@2
                inputs:
                  targetType: 'inline'
                  script: |
                    # Write your PowerShell commands here.
                    Write-Host $(thissupersecret)
  - stage: 'DeployStage'
    dependsOn: 'BuildStage'
    condition: succeeded('BuildStage')
    displayName: 'DeployStage'
    jobs: 
      - deployment: DeployStageSecretconsumerjobs      # deployment is equal to job
        variables:
          thissupersecret: $[stageDependencies.BuildStage.BuildStageSecretProducerjobs.outputs['mastertask.supersecret']]
        environment: dev
        displayName: 'DeployStageSecretconsumerjobs'
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
              - checkout: none
              - download: none
              - task: PowerShell@2
                inputs:
                  targetType: 'inline'
                  script: |
                    # Write your PowerShell commands here.
                    Write-Host $(thissupersecret)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$releaseurl = ('{0}{1}/_apis/release/releases/{2}?api-version=5.0' -f $($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONSERVERURI), $($env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID), $($env:RELEASE_RELEASEID)  )

$Release = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $releaseurl -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}

$variableName = '<HERE_VARIABLE_NAME>'
$release.variables.($variableName).value = "<YOUR VALUE HERE IN STRING OR REFERNCE TO A VARIABLE E.G. $(OTHER_VARIABLE)>"

$json = @($release) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $releaseurl -Method Put -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" }

$Release = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $releaseurl -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}
```

Above is 100% working for Releases in ADO. Try to dig for URLs referencing Builds and you should be fine. Of course is you opt to Powershell.

Comment: Not looking for this, And my question is what's wrong with my approach.

Comment: OK, checked your code and see this:
thissupersecret: $[ dependencies.BuildStageSecretProducerjobs.outputs['masterjob.supersecret'] ] refers to masterjob and should to mastertask

and also this part I think is fine: $[stageDependencies.BuildStage.BuildStageSecretProducerjobs.outputs['mastertask.supersecret']]

Comment: Did you mean, No error in my code, Still it is not working?

Comment: No, here I see error: " $[ dependencies.BuildStageSecretProducerjobs.outputs['masterjob.supersecret'] ] ==> refers to masterjob and should to mastertask".

Other part looks ok, maybe this above error blocks proper working of the rest sections